# Using Object as Value in Angular Select Option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, object

Given the following jade in an Angular view like below, how can I use an object as the value?

```
div(ng-app='MyApp', ng-controller='MyCtrl')
  div(ng-repeat='localField in localClientFields',ng-cloak)
    select(ng-model='localField.remote_field',ng-change='changeField(localField)')
      option(ng-repeat='field in remoteFields',ng-value='{{field.data}}') {{field.label}}
    div           
      pre {{localField|json}}
```

For reference, the data looks like so:

```
$scope.remoteFields = [{ 
    "label": "Studio Name", 
    "data": { 
        "field_id": 122566593, 
        "type": "text", 
        "external_id": "studio-name" 
        } 
    }, { 
    "label": "Membership Status", 
    "data": { 
        "field_id": 122562654, 
        "type": "category", 
        "external_id": "premier-status" 
        } 
    }
];
```

[See this in action in this JSBin](https://jsbin.com/jazahejaho/1/edit?html,css,js,output)

**NOTES:**

1. When I do it as above (using `value`), it results in the value being a JSON string represenation of the object, such as `"{\"field_id\":122562654,\"type\":\"category\",\"external_id\":\"premier-status\"}"}`.
2. When I do it as an `ng-value="field.data"`, the value results in the string `[Object Object]`.
3. For some other reasons, I've been unable to use `select(ng-options="remoteFields")` (but *this is set up* in the JSBin) - but that *does* appear to properly allow assignment of the object as the value.

What am I missing? I know that with other elements (such as radio buttons, checkboxes, etc) you can assign an object as the value.  What gives in this scenario?

And - for bonus points - why doesn't the `ng-options` method in the pasteBin properly pre-select the option?

Comment: Use `ng-options` and `track by` statement  instead of using `ng-repeat`

Comment: @charlietfl - did you look at my jsbin? Did you read my notes? I indicated that was causing some problems - I'm happy to use it, but there is still a question there around how to solve the pre-select in the case of  `ng-options`